# How can only giving number of channels and no height and width to my convolutional neural network work?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

Hello I am a bit new to the deep learning community and I have been really fed up with how to feed in data throught a neural network. So I was doing the sentdex pytorch series and I was learning convnets. He was using the cats and dogs dataset of microsoft on kaggle. He had resized the image to 50 by 50 and turned them into grayscale. If you want to see the video to answer my question here it is -
https://pythonprogramming.net/convnet-model-deep-learning-neural-network-pytorch/

So a few thoughts came in my mind while watching the video. The input he passed is only the colour channel of the image -

[image]

At once at seeing the input he entered it came in my mind why is he only passing the number of channels which is a grayscale image. When a conv2d takes 3 inputs.
[image]

And I mean it litterally works. I tried researching a bit but no where I found a  good explaination for the input shape that is being fed in here

So I have 2 thoughts and questions about this -

- So does that line mean that the convolutional neural network will
  only take in an image that is grayscale and is of any height and
  width and if so please tell how to limit the dimensions like that to
  make our cnn only accept a input shape of `(50, 50, 1)`.
- And if not then please explain what does it mean, and how we can make
  it accept any input.

Comment: Are you confused about the ordering of dimensions for the input?  The normal order is (batch, channel, length) for 1d and (batch, channel, width, height) for 2d.  The convolution occurs over the last dimension for 1d and the last 2 for 2d.

Comment: Batch can be passed while training of the neural network in pytorch as I know. We can do this simply - batch_x.view(-1, 50, 50, 1). So that can be passed into our network I think @John. So you say that convolution occurs over the last 2 dimensions of 2d, that is  width and height, but sentdex hasn't specified those things. Please tell me if I am a bit wrong about the batch size thingy because I am new to deep learning in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convolutional layers use the convolution operation i.e. sliding of a kernel (matrix) over the input and taking the sum of elementwise products at each position while sliding. Thus, the input dimensions will affect the output dimensions, however, it is not necessary to fix the input dimensions.

Thus, the layer can be defined as `nn.Conv2d(1, 32, 5)` where 1 indicates number of channels of input, 32 is number of channels of output, and 5 is the size of the kernel (it is 5x5 in this case since it is 2D).

The 32 output channels will actually mean that there will be 32 such 5x5 kernels which will be applied to the input and each output will be stacked to get an output of `h` x `w` x 32. Note that this `h` and `w` will be different than the `h_in` and `w_in` in case of not using padding, but same if you use padding.

1 input channel mentioned in the layer means that the layer will accept only single channeled inputs (which are effectively grayscale images).

If you  want to limit your CNN to use (50, 50, 1) inputs only, then you can resize the image before feeding it (you can do that using OpenCV).

Check [this site](https://github.com/vdumoulin/conv_arithmetic) for some animations of convolutions.

Update: Adding more things asked in the comments by the OP.

Yes, you can input images of any shape (I suppose they still have to be at least the size of the kernel). So, theoretically, you can input any image to a convolutional layer, but not necessarily to your CNN. That is because the CNN may have flattening operations followed by fully connected layers (`nn.Linear`). These flattening + fully connected will expect certain dimensions (which are fixed by you in the code), so you cannot give any input image to your CNN i.e. you have to ensure that flattening the last convolutional layer's output has dimensions equal to your first fully connected layer's dimensions.

Edit: You can actually give any sized input even for a CNN containing fully-connected layers by using a Global Average Pooling (GAP) layer to reduce the size to a fixed size irrespective of the input size. It is called [Adaptive Average Pooling](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d.html#torch.nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d) in PyTorch.

For example, consider this network (image attached)[image]
In this, the convolutional kernels sizes are mentioned below the arrows, and the blue cuboids represent the output after each convolutional layer. At the end, there are fully connected layers (boxes with circles) which have fixed dimensions. So, the last convolutional layer output has dimensions 6*6*256 = 9216, which is also the dimension of the first fully connected layer.

So, basically, you design your network such that the last convolutional output flattened has same dimensions as the first fully connected layer. Note that there are some networks called Fully Convolutional Networks (FCNs) which don't use these fully connected layers and thus are input size independent. The network design and choice of layers depends on your application.

Comment: So does that mean I can input images of any shape by only writing the input channel that is to be accepted. And by the way I want to know how to only pass images in the forward method. In the input shape of my network. Not by reshaping or resizing. Because that I know how to do. Please explain these things also to me and making your answer a bit more informatic. Thanks for your answer.@akshayk07

Comment: I have updated the answer with an example. And also tried to answer your questions. Also, I would suggest you to go through some online course on Deep Learning or Neural Networks for better understanding (rather than some application based videos like sentdex or Siraj Raval).

Comment: Thanks for telling the information i needed @akshay07. You deserve an upvote which I have given you. But what about the limiting the cnn to a particular input like to make it accept only 50 by 50 size images. Please also tell me this. I do not want to know the reshaping or resizing the image method which I know. Just for curiosity sake please tell me how to make our net accept only particular inputs in the input convolutional layer.

Comment: Really speaking you can't restrict the input size that way (because of the way the Convolutional layers are designed in most frameworks like PyTorch or even TensorFlow I think). Still, if you want to force that, you can put an if condition which checks the dimensions before executing the forward pass.

Comment: do you mean that passing an input like (50, 50, 1) won't work

Comment: 50x50 grayscale image will work. But you have to reshape it such that the dimensions should be (batch_size, channels, height, width). That is required in PyTorch (you can go through PyTorch [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/index.html) and [tutorials](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/) to get an idea).